# Center buttons in second column with flexible width?

Tags: html, css, layout, stylesheet

How do I center the red and yellow blue buttons within `#top-menu`?

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/qKXD2/

My problem is I want `#top-menu` to stay on the right side and not overlapping the whole screen width. Right now anything within `#top-menu` is center to the screen itself.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to center the logo(yellow) and #top-menu buttons(red & blue) in #header...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `float:left` from the button styles and add `display:inline-block.` 
Add `overflow:auto` to `#top-menu .center`

**Explanation**

`Float:left`: makes your div to align exact left to the parent div.

`disply:block:` Makes the div to occupy the entire horizontal space.

`Overflow:auto`: Makes parent div to extend based on the content inside ot.

Since you need to place the two divs next to each other give `inline-block`. inline-block makes div to be expanded based on the content inside the div.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKXD2/5/)**

Comment: This works by add just `autoflow:auto` and no need to remove `float:left` or add `inline-block`. Can you explain what happened here and why it works? I read this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp on overflow and it doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: I think only `overflow:auto` matters here as you can see my modify http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/qKXD2/7/ since I added it without removing 'float:left'. I guess my previous css doesn't work because `#top-menu .center` doesn't have a width value (based in Firebug when clicking on `.center` in element list). When I added `overflow:auto`, then it had the `width`. This works although the `#top-menu` still has the full width of the screen (black border in above link). Why does css have this behavior?

Comment: but I dont feel that blue and red buttons are center aligned to topmenu div. You can extend the result part and see the effect. And check the same in my demo http://jsfiddle.net/qKXD2/5/

Comment: Oh I see what's going on. Your solution set all buttons centered within the green border (`.center`): http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/qKXD2/10/ while mine still puts buttons in left align (although the `.center` is actually centered now): http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/qKXD2/11/. But still the question about the mechanic of `margin:auto` thing: `#left-menu` (with black border) is spanned across the screen 100%, so even with the fixes above, why would the `.center` is NOT centered from the width of the screen, just based on logic. Because originally, I was thinking about fixing `#left-menu` width instead.

Answer (score 2):

change #top-menu .center and #logo styles like these I think this is what you want

```
#logo {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  position:absolute;
 }


#top-menu .center {
  width: 235px;
  margin auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKXD2/9/)

Comment: Well, my width is intended to be 235px for other design reasons (e.g. there are more than 2 buttons, etc..)

Comment: check my new answer with more than 2 button ,etc. maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution. remove float left in logo and put margin:0 auto; see the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/qKXD2/6/

Many Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I rather want to keep the blue and red buttons in same horizontal bar...

Answer (score 0):

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qKXD2/12/) for the center logo and top-menu on header.